# kie workbench 6.2.0.CR2 installer fails to start: Unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, jbpm

When trying to start the demo in Jbpm-distribution-6.2.0.CR2-installer.zip the service fails to start, ie the log says:
Services which failed to start:service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService

Earlier in the (very long) log I see an error trace referring to the problem:
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ProjectService with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.validation.JavaFileNameValidator.projectService

I raised it as an issue on the [JIRA](https://hudson.jboss.org/jenkins/job/jBPM/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/jbpm-distribution/target/) but after a couple of weeks an no answer I'm trying here. I've tried it on several versions of 6.2.0 now: Beta2, CR1 and CR2. Since it is a complete show stopper for the demo I'm wondering if it is something peculiar to my machine.

Does anyone else have this running okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you behind a proxy or firewall? Have you tried starting the demo without the examples that are cloned from a public repo?